# MySQL Copying to tmp table causing hang

Tags: mysql

I have a 'simple' query:

```
SELECT searchterm, count(searchterm) as intNumHits
FROM site_searches 
WHERE searchdate >= 20151202 AND searchdate <= 20151202 
GROUP BY searchterm 
ORDER BY intNumHits DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

site_searches is > 7.5 million rows.

searchterm & searchdate are indexed.

From other answers on here, the **max_heap_table_size** and **tmp_table_size** are questioned. My settings are:

> max_heap_table_size: 16777216
>
> tmp_table_size: 264241152

But, when I run the query, it seems to hang on "Copying to tmp table".

If I remove the count(searchterm) and GROUP BY options, the query runs, but still takes 19 seconds!

Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:

Running EXPLAIN on the query gives the following:

```
id = 1
select_type = SIMPLE
table = site_searches
type = index
possible_keys = searchdate
key = searchterm
key_len = 767
ref = NULL
rows = 7431801
Extra = Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Thanks

Comment: is there a good index on searchdate and intNumHits  and searchterm?

Comment: try to execute the query with EXPLAIN ahead (EXPLAIN SELECT etc. etc), and post the result. With explain we can see how the query use the index.

Comment: show desc site_searches, see if searchdate is int ? if its char, then use quotes ex . '20151202'

Comment: please show the results of , SHOW CREATE TABLE `site_searches`

Comment: @Hytool - it's the date serials! They are not int's so the quotes works. Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see if searchdate datatype is int ? if its char, then use quotes ex . '20151202'

```
    SELECT searchterm, count(searchterm) as intNumHits
    FROM site_searches 
    WHERE searchdate >= '20151202' AND searchdate <= '20151202' 
    GROUP BY searchterm 
    ORDER BY intNumHits DESC 
    LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: That's the solution - query now takes 0.168s to run! Thank you.

Comment: Glad, it worked ! Sometimes, SQL tuning requires very small changes !